# 2D Heat Equation - Exact Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve numerically the heat equation on a rectangle, with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and a source term.

$u_t = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + Q(x,y,t,u) \qquad \text{in} \quad 0<x<1, \quad 0<y<2, \quad t>0$

with

$u=0 \quad \text{on} \quad x=0,1, \quad y=0,2.$

while

$u (t=0) = u_0(x,y) $

I want to test my code with an exact solution but I can´t find any for this particular case. Do you know any book, website, resource in which example solutions to this equation can be found?

Thank you

Comment: Applied PDEs by Haberman will have it (or something very similar to it).  It'll probably be what you need.

Comment: see here: http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf the geometry is simple, so you may want to try and separate variables